# Successful swap but didnt received the token in my wallet

Tags: metamask, uniswap

I did 2 swaps using Uniswap on Ethereum network.

1st one: [.](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xaa0141c61b02099c2f25d3ee1c7fc7c18b2d5d02542cea86af40b1d4426ea1b2), it didn't appear on my metamask wallet.

2nd one:
[.](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x84bfe276b4727bf38ce9c95f8d2c451b14903f06d79460696251e2de73da403f), it appeared on my metamask wallet.

How do I retrieve the 1st swap to my wallet? Thanks!

Comment: Please mention the chain/network that you've used.

Comment: sorry, i was using eth network. those are txn hash i get in ehterscan

Comment: If the second one went through the first one went through. Have you looked at your address with an explorer. Is it just not showing in your wallet UI as in you need to add the contract address?
Are you willing to share transaction hash?